# Multilingual site and domains

Tags: .htaccess-configuration, url, multilingual

I have a multilingual joomla site setup and would like to use a different domain for each language.

So instead of "englishsite.com/en/" and "englishsite.com/fr/",
I would get "englishsite.com/" and "frenchsite.com/". 
And the domains and language would switch with the Joomla language switcher module.

Could this be done with Chameleon component, or .htaccess redirects?
Should I use something like Falang for translations instead of Joomla Core setup?

Answer (score 2):

(I'm not familiar with [Chameleon](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/style-a-design/templating/11173), but from what I see after a quick look, you could be able to make it work.)

However, the Joomla Documentation has an [article regarding a similar example](http://docs.joomla.org/Multiple_Domains_and_Web_Sites_in_a_single_Joomla!_installation), with a couple of different approaches. You should take a look at it.

The following should work, although I haven't tested it (based on option #3 from the link above):

Basically, you set up your cPanel with a main domain (`englishsite.com`) and an addon domain (`frenchsite.com`). Then you could tweak the following code to fit your needs, and add it to your templates `index.php` AT THE VERY BEGINNING:

```
<?php
$domain = $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];
$requri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if (($domain == "www.englishsite.com" && $requri == "/" || 
   $domain == "englishsite.com"))  { 
   header("Status: 301 Moved Permanently");
   header("Location: http://www.englishsite.com/en"); 
}
if (($domain == "www.frenchsite.com" && $requri == "/" || 
   $domain == "frenchsite.com"))  { 
   header("Status: 301 Moved Permanently");
   header("Location: http://www.frenchsite.com/fr"); 
}
?>
```

Make sure you enable SEF urls for your site (Global Configuration -> SEO settings).

Finally, go to the plugin manager and locate the plugin `System - Language Filter`. In the plugin settings, set "Remove URL Language Code" to Yes.

[image: Language Filter plugin]

Comment: I do not have cPanel as my hosting provider does not offer it. Both domains are directed to the same folder. It was working for a few minutes and then stopped working...  I think I'm having difficulties with the homepage as well, on the englishsite.com when I go back to the homepage it sends me back to the frenchsite.com. I've gotten redirect error pages trying to make it work.